# Team Foundation Server 2015 Test Results

Tags: unit-testing, tfs, code-coverage, tfs-2015

When i build my project in TFS 2015, I have set up to run all Unit tests/code coverage. The tests run and all of them pass. The issue i am having is that the results don't show up at the summary of the build or any where. Any reason why not showing up?

I looked at the logs and i am getting this warning:

> Results File:
>   C:\BuildAgent_work\1\TestResults\serverName$_serverName 2015-12-03
>   15_56_33.trx
>
> Total tests: 533. Passed: 533.
>   Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
>
> Test Run Successful.
>
> Test execution time: 29.5985 Seconds
>
> Publishing Test Results...
>
> ##[warning]Invalid results file.
>   Please make sure the Test Result Format field in the task matches the
>   result format of the file:
>   C:\BuildAgent_work\1\TestResults\serverName$_serverName 2015-12-03
>   15_56_33.trx

I looked at the file

serverName$_serverName 2015-12-03 15_56_33.trx`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <TestRun id="730b84f3-e06c-4d30-8994-15aa6ff385df" name="serverName$@serverName 2015-12-03 15:56:33" runUser="NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Times creation="2015-12-03T15:56:33.2204061-05:00" queuing="2015-12-03T15:56:33.2204061-05:00" start="2015-12-03T15:56:33.2204061-05:00" finish="2015-12-03T15:57:01.4723683-05:00" />
  <TestSettings name="default" id="d53ac855-fee0-4c64-9372-227e08990a04">
    <Execution>
      <TestTypeSpecific />
    </Execution>
    <Deployment runDeploymentRoot="serverName$_serverName 2015-12-03 15_56_33" />
    <Properties />
  </TestSettings>
  <TestLists>
    <TestList name="Results Not in a List" id="8c84fa94-04c1-424b-9868-57a2d4851a1d" />
    <TestList name="All Loaded Results" id="19431567-8539-422a-85d7-44ee4e166bda" />
  </TestLists>
  <ResultSummary outcome="Completed">
    <Counters total="0" executed="0" passed="0" failed="0" error="0" timeout="0" aborted="0" inconclusive="0" passedButRunAborted="0" notRunnable="0" notExecuted="0" disconnected="0" warning="0" completed="0" inProgress="0" pending="0" />
    <Output>
      <StdOut>NUnit 1.2.0.0 executing tests is startedLoading tests from C:\BuildAgent\_work\1\a\App.Tests.dllRun started: C:\BuildAgent\_work\1\a\App.Tests.dllLoading tests from C:\BuildAgent\_work\1\a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dllRun started: C:\BuildAgent\_work\1\a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dllNUnit 1.2.0.0 executing tests is finished</StdOut>
    </Output>
    <RunInfos>
      <RunInfo computerName="serverName" outcome="Warning" timestamp="2015-12-03T15:56:31.8163881-05:00">
        <Text>Diagnostic data adapter message: Could not find diagnostic data adapter of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector' and Uri 'datacollector://microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0'.</Text>
      </RunInfo>
      <RunInfo computerName="serverName" outcome="Warning" timestamp="2015-12-03T15:56:32.8460013-05:00">
        <Text>Unable to create DiaSession for C:\BuildAgent\_work\1\a\App.Tests.dll
No source location data will be available for this assembly.</Text>
      </RunInfo>
      <RunInfo computerName="serverName" outcome="Warning" timestamp="2015-12-03T15:57:01.1759645-05:00">
        <Text>System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded AppDomain. This can happen if the test(s) started a thread but did not stop it. Make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are stopped before completion.</Text>
      </RunInfo>
    </RunInfos>
  </ResultSummary>
</TestRun>
```

Comment: What version of Visual Studio is installed on the build agent?

Comment: Are you using XAML build or vNext build? Is this project new created? Could you share your detailed steps how to create your solution and how to build?

Comment: I had the wrong version of VS. Uninstall 2013 and install 2015 and everything is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was with the Visual Studio in the build server. Once i updated Visual Studio from 2013 to 2015 in the build server everything worked fine.